# can ddwrt be configured to alert me if an unknown device logs on to my wireless network?

Tags: wireless-networking, dd-wrt

can i give **ddwrt** a white list for this purpose?  note that  I do not want to restrict devices that are not on the list from logging in. I just want to see if they do log on.

Comment: in addition, 
if I do decide to create a white list to restrict usage to authorized devices only, can I get alerted when other devices try to log on?

Comment: Did you ever get a real answer to this?

Comment: Not Really , at least not an easy to use answer but the other member did point me towards a potential solution. I just havent had time yet to really look at it and see if it solves the original Q

Comment: Let us know when you do. I'm curious myself. What version of dd-wrt are you using? It would be beneficial to the question.

Answer (score 0):

See the article
[GatewayAPl - Rock solid SMS gateway](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/dd-wrt-unknown-client-notification-lars-erik-storbuk%C3%A5s/).

The article shows how to configure a DD-WRT router to run a custom script upon
DHCP lease/renewal, that notifies about unknown clients connecting to
the router by sending an SMS to the specified recipient.

You need to pay the website for sending an SMS, so this part us not useful,
but the rest of the tutorial is still worth reading.
It starts with the following commands:

```
mkdir -p /jffs/etc/scripts
vi /jffs/etc/scripts/dhcp-lease-notifier.sh       (enter script)
chmod +x /jffs/etc/scripts/dhcp-lease-notifier.sh
```

Finally, add the following DNSMasq option at
*Services > Services > DNSMasq > Additional DNSMasq Options*
with the following line:

```
dhcp-script=/jffs/etc/scripts/dhcp-lease-notifier.sh
```

There is no point in reproducing the entire script here,
except to note that it finds the known MAC list in
`/jffs/etc/scripts/known_mac_addr`, and that it contains
these lines that you could use:

```
known_mac_addr="/jffs/etc/scripts/known_mac_addr"
grep -q "$2" "$known_mac_addr"
unknown_mac_addr=$?
if [ "$unknown_mac_addr" -ne 0 ]; then
```

Comment: thanks! I will take a close look at this ...  QUESTION: when you say pay 'the website' to send an sms'  which website are you referring to?   cant i instead have the script send me an email or a pop up alert to my laptop?

unless im completely missing something... the script runs on the router/device and NOT on my laptop so it would have to do some  kind fo telnet to a computer on the LAN that the device is connected to?

Comment: The website of the link apparently does SMS as a paid service, but you may replace that part by any other method, such as email.